# Renaming jpg file in PHP

Tags: php

I have an upload functionality wherein I want to check whether there is a duplicate filename in the database. If there is, I would like to rename the jpg so that the photo to be uploaded will still be uploaded.

Here's the lines of codes that I came up with:

```
$shuffled = "qwertyuiopasdfghjkZxcvbnm";
$shuffled = str_shuffle($shuffled); 
$shuffled = $shuffled.".jpg";
rename($this->filename,$shuffled);
```

I am using the shuffle function here to somehow give a random new filename,
I have tried using some other steps like preg_replace, but the jpg file itself gets corrupted. Any ideas?

Comment: Not related to the question, but a random filename could still cause duplicates, you may as well append increasing numbers to the end of the filename

Comment: So the problem is the file is getting corrupted?

Comment: The problem is, when I rename the file by treating the filename as string, the file itself gets corrupted.

Comment: are you saving the file using something like: (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is:

```
$shuffled = "qwertyuiopasdfghjkZxcvbnm";
$shuffled = str_shuffle($shuffled); 
$shuffled = $shuffle.".jpg";
rename($this->filename,$shuffled);
```

The third line looks like it should be $shuffled = $shuffled.".jpg";

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
copy($oldfilename,rand(10000000000,99999999999).".jpeg");
unlink($oldfilename);
```

the file name (without extension) will be a number greater than 10000000000 and smallet than 99999999999

Answer (score 0):

Where is the extension in your new filename???

Exmple

```
rename("/tmp/tmp_file.txt", "/home/user/login/docs/my_file.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a random filename, use microtime() to generate a random string. 
A nicer solution would be:

```
if(is_file($filename))
{
$filenameSplit = explode('.', $filename);
$i = 1;
while(is_file($filenameSplit[0] . "($i)." . $filenameSplit[1]))
{
$i++;
}
$newFilename = $filenameSplit[0] . "($i)." . $filenameSplit[1];
rename($filename, $newFilename);
}
```